# SSRS (report builder) sorting a row

Tags: sql, sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

My requirement is I have to sort a row Month Wise, that is Jan, Feb, Mar etc right now it is not sorted.

I have tried writing query under query window order by case when...

I have tried writing query in expression of month field i.e.

```
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Feb-19", 2,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Mar-19", 3,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Apr-19", 4,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "May-19", 5,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Jun-19", 6,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Jul-19", 7,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Aug-19", 8,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Sep-19", 9,
   IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Oct-19", 10,
IIF(Fields!Month_Y.Value = "Nov-19", 11, 12)))))))))))
```

I have wrote same IIF condition query in Tablix - Sorting expression field too.

But still it is not sorting the report month wise. if anyone can have a look and give the solution please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you certain that Month_Y is exactly as you expect? check for leading.trailing spaces

Answer (score 1):

I understand from your question that you tried to use "case" on the "data set"

> I have tried writing query under query window order by case when...

So the next thing that you need to do is:

1. Right-click on the column.
2. Go to "Shorting".
3. Press "Add".
4. Choose your "number" column(that you mapped - "Feb-19" etc.).
5. Choose your order method "Z-A" or "A-Z".

I simulated your case and it worked for me.

See the image below

[image]

Comment: Hi @Benzi thank you for your reply. I tried it is not working, can you please more steps. I have to put Union all query too after order by case when clause in query window. It is giving me error of Union keyword which I had used. and by sorting order it is not working for me.

Comment: Are you using SQL server? please post the query that you have on your "data-set".

Comment: Hi it is solved now, I had to apply above query in group properties > sorting field. As i was sorting by groups so all good  now. thank you for help